# How to run automated script for postgresql backup

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I was in need to backup my postgresql database on a daily basis.I found the solution from wiki (https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Automated_Backup_on_Linux). Thanks to opensource community for the guide but I am getting confused where and how to keep and run the script. 
I am using linux ubuntu 14.04 as a server and is newbie on this. I have found solutions using cron but there are many crons at /etc like cron.d, cron.daily etc. Please help me out, if possible by linking to tutorial or some steps guide.

Comment: `cron` utility may be used to configure schedule in linux: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto

Comment: I tried with cron but it does not run the whole code. It only copies the config file and does not run rest of the code. When I run "pg_backup.sh" from terminal it gives error at line8. I am unable to find the bug.